# Storybook: "Unexpected token r in JSON at position 27"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, storybook

Storybook used to crash because I use aliases defined in webpack. I thus modified the main.js config of Storybook to add them manually. When launching the build, Storybook crashes with the following error:

> Unexpected token r in JSON at position 27

Here is the config:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  stories: ["../**/stories.tsx"],
  webpackFinal: (config) => {
    return {
      ...config,
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          api: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/api/"),
          assets: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets/"),
          components: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components/"),
          containers: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/containers/"),
          i18n: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/i18n/"),
          models: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/models/"),
          pages: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/pages/"),
          src: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/"),
          stores: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/stores/"),
          utils: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/utils/"),
        },
      },
      module: {
        ...config.module,
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: { loader: "babel-loader" },
          },
          { test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] },
          { test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, use: ["file-loader"] },
          {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: "babel-loader",
              },
              {
                loader: "react-svg-loader",
                options: {
                  jsx: true,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  },
  typescript: {
    check: false,
    checkOptions: {},
    reactDocgen: "react-docgen-typescript",
    reactDocgenTypescriptOptions: {
      shouldExtractLiteralValuesFromEnum: true,
      propFilter: (prop) =>
        prop.parent ? !/node_modules/.test(prop.parent.fileName) : true,
    },
  },
};
```

My app structure looks like this:

- client

  - storybook

    - main.js
    - preview.js
  - src

    - components
    - pages
  - webpack.config.js

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you resolve this? It looks like you have a lot of redundant commas in there, not sure if removing those would make a difference?

Comment: Hi, I used tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin it solved the issue.